# JavaScript loses image movement function when using a DOCTYPE

Tags: php, javascript, html, doctype

I have got a JavaScript here that is suppose to make an image (ghost) appear on screen, fly around for a bit, and then fade out before repeating again later on. The script works just fine without a DOCTYPE in my document, however if I add any DOCTYPEs, only the appear/disappear works. For some reason it doesn't move around on screen. The DOCTYPE I need to use is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This has been driving me crazy and I can't seem to figure out how to make it compatible. I just need to get the movement portion working with a DOCTYPE. Any help with this would really be appreciated. Below is the script:

```
if(!window.JSFX) JSFX=new Object();
JSFX.ghostImages = new Array( 
    "<img src='/ghost.png'>",
    "<img src='/ghost2.png'>"
);
var ns4 = document.layers;
var ie4 = document.all;
JSFX.makeLayer = function(id)
{
    var el =        document.getElementById ? document.getElementById(id) :
                    document.all            ? document.all[id] :
                                                      document.layers[id];
    if(ns4) el.style=el;
    el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.right = x;this.style.top=y;};
    el.show=function(){ this.style.visibility = "visible"; } 
    el.hide=function(){ this.style.visibility = "hidden"; } 
    if(ns4 || window.opera) 
            el.sO = function(pc){return 0;};
    else if(ie4)
            el.sO = function(pc)
            {
                    if(this.style.filter=="")
                            this.style.filter="alpha(opacity=100);";
                    this.filters.alpha.opacity=pc;
            }
    else
            el.sO = function(pc)
{
this.style.opacity=pc/100;
}

    return el;
}

if(window.innerWidth)
{
    gX=function(){return innerWidth;};
    gY=function(){return innerHeight;};
}
else
{
    gX=function(){return document.body.width-50;};
    gY=function(){return document.body.height-50;};
}
JSFX.ghostOutput=function()
{
    for(var i=0 ; i<JSFX.ghostImages.length ; i++)
            document.write(ns4 ? "<LAYER  NAME='gh"+i+"'>"+JSFX.ghostImages[i]+"<\/LAYER>" : 
                                       "<DIV id='gh"+i+"'     style='position:absolute'>"+JSFX.ghostImages[i]+"<\/DIV>" );

}
JSFX.ghostSprites = new Array();
JSFX.ghostStartAni = function()
{
    for(var i=0 ;i<JSFX.ghostImages.length;i++)
    {
            var el=JSFX.makeLayer("gh"+i);
            el.x=Math.random()*gX();
            el.y=Math.random()*gY();
            el.tx=Math.random()*gX();
            el.ty=Math.random()*gY();
            el.dx=-5+Math.random()*10;
            el.dy=-5+Math.random()*10;
            el.state="off";
            el.op=0;
            el.sO(el.op);
            el.hide();
            JSFX.ghostSprites[i] = el;
    }
    setInterval("JSFX.ghostAni()", 40);
}
JSFX.ghostAni = function()
{
    for(var i=0 ;i<JSFX.ghostSprites.length;i++)
    {
            el=JSFX.ghostSprites[i];

            if(el.state == "off")
            {
                    if(Math.random() > .99)
                    {
                            el.state="up";
                            el.show();
                    }
            }
            else if(el.state == "on")
            {
                    if(Math.random() > .98)
                            el.state="down";
            }
            else if(el.state == "up")
            {
                    el.op += 2;
                    el.sO(el.op);
                    if(el.op==100)
                            el.state = "on";
            }
            else if(el.state == "down")
            {
                    el.op -= 2;
                    if(el.op==0)
                    {
                            el.hide();
                            el.state = "off";
                    }
                    else
                            el.sO(el.op);
            }

            var X = (el.tx - el.x);
            var Y = (el.ty - el.y);
            var len = Math.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y);
            if(len < 1) len = 1;
            var dx = 20 * (X/len);
            var dy = 20 * (Y/len);
            var ddx = (dx - el.dx)/10;
            var ddy = (dy - el.dy)/10;
            el.dx += ddx;
            el.dy += ddy;
            el.sP(el.x+=el.dx,el.y+=el.dy);

            if(Math.random() >.95 )
            {
                    el.tx = Math.random()*gX();
                    el.ty = Math.random()*gY();
            }

    }
}
JSFX.ghostStart = function()
{
    if(JSFX.ghostLoad)JSFX.ghostLoad();
    JSFX.ghostStartAni();
}
JSFX.ghostOutput();
JSFX.ghostLoad=window.onload;
window.onload=JSFX.ghostStart;
```

Here is an example of the script on a page without a DOCTYPE:
http://boomansion.net/test.php

...and an exmaple on a page with a DOCTYPE (look at the very bottom):
http://boomansion.net/test2.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What DOCTYPE? And can you provide an example?

Comment: I have added an example of with and without a DOCTYPE. Check below the script.

Comment: I suggest you use an abstraction library like jQuery to save you a lot of trouble. And you should validate the sourcecode, it's full of errors. And: You do not need to set a doctype normally. Skip it if it saves you the hassles. Your page looks equally good with or without the doctype in my eyes. If you *need* to the doctype, fix all errors the page is reporting, you have to serious issues with test2.php: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fboomansion.net%2Ftest2.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 4):

You set setting `top` and `left` to Numbers, but they take lengths (and non-zero lengths **must** have a unit).

When you add a Doctype, browsers:

- Assume you know what you are doing
- Follow the specification more closely
- (Consequently) are more consistent with each other
- (Consequently) will treat more errors are "values to ignore" instead of "values to fix up automatically".

You probably want to `+ "px"`.

Comment: Not exactly. The code, as written, has errors that the browser will only recover from when in Quirks mode. The Doctype triggers Standards mode, and the browser won't recover from those errors any more (it will do what the specification says it should do instead). So the issue is that the code is generating invalid CSS, but that Quirks mode masks the problem.

Comment: That's what I meant (good explanation though). I don't know that I've ever considered that not having quirks mode for a script could be an issue.

Comment: Note that just the presence of a DOCTYPE does not *necessarily* trigger quirks mode.  [It has to be the right kind of DOCTYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get IE into standards mode (or, vice-versa).